# SQL select records if the sum is grater than or equal to two

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I want to show the company name and the number of products that a company supplies as long as the number of products are more than two.

Here is the extract from the Supplier table:

```
SupplierID    CompanyName       . . . 
1             Exotic Liquids
2             New Orleans Cajun 
3             Grandma Kelly's   
.
.
```

Here is the extract from the Products table:

```
ProductId   ProductName      SupplierID  CategoryID .  .
1           Chai             1           1
2           Chang            1           1
3           Aniseed Syrup    1           2
4           Cajun Seasoning  2           2
5           Gumbo Mix        2           2
6           Berry Spread     3           2
.
.
```

SQL code I used:

```
SELECT   S.CompanyName , (SUM(P.SupplierID)) AS 'Number of Products'
FROM     Suppliers S, Products P
WHERE    P.SupplierID = S.SupplierID
GROUP BY S.CompanyName
ORDER BY SUM(P.SupplierID) >= 3
```

With the above code MSSQL server gives me an `Incorrect syntax near '>'` error.
I have no idea how to fix this to get something like the following as my results:

```
CompanyName        Number of Products

Exotic Liquids     5
New Orleans Cajun  8
Grandma Kelly's    3
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server, or MySQL?

Comment: Did you mean `HAVING` instead of `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `having` clause to filter on the number of products per company. Even in MySQL, where the query does not fails, it doesn't to what you want: it puts companies that have 3 or more products first, but does not evicts the from the resultset.

Also, consider using *standard* joins rather than old-school, implicit joins.

```
select s.companyName, count(*) no_products
from suppliers s
inner join products p on p.supplierID = s.supplierID
group by s.supplierID, s.companyName
having count(*) >= 3
order by s.supplierID
```

Note that in SQL Server, you could also use an lateral join for this, which might be more efficient:

```
select s.*, p.no_products
from suppliers
cross apply (select count(*) no_products from products p where p.supplierID = s.supplierID) p
where p.no_products >= 3
order by s.supplierID
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I now see my mistake.

Comment: @EttienneVanZyl: not a problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   
        S.CompanyName
    ,   'Number of Products'    =   SUM(1)

FROM    @Supplier   S
JOIN    @Product    P   ON  P.SupplierID    =   S.SupplierID

GROUP BY 
        S.CompanyName

HAVING  SUM(1) > 2
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.